# Triggered email not sent to few people

Tags: exm

ClientApi does not send email to a few email ids and sends to a few randomly on email signup. Could the opt-out list play any role here? We are on `Sitecore8.1`

Also the `Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentManagement.Config` has

```
<setting name="StandardMessages.DefaultGlobalOptOutList"          value="/sitecore/system/List Manager/All Lists/E-mail Campaign     Manager/System/Common Global Opt-out" />
```

I don't see any records on this list.  How am I supposed to know if people that unsubscribe made an entry in an opt-out list? And if yes if they subscribe again they will never receive an email since they are in the opt-out list.

Where do I check records in an opt-out list?

Also, I see **Error in Exm Log:**

```
19012 10:19:51 INFO  Registered email: eservices@email.gocollette.com
15688 10:19:51 DEBUG Message 'US DTC 64UJR Newsletter Signup Email': Recipient is skipped. **No email address was associated with recipient 'xdb:ca19b013-255b-4ec7-a0ae-4586fe3496ec'.**
ManagedPoolThread #7 10:19:51 INFO  Dispatch Message (US DTC 64UJR Newsletter Signup Email): Started
  Message Id:      {218AE469-3025-4AE3-AB07-C9E52BD68403}
  Message Path:    /sitecore/content/Home/Email Campaign/Messages/Triggered Emails/Triggered Emails 2016/US DTC 64UJR Newsletter Signup Email
  Included Recipient Lists: 
  Excluded Recipient Lists:
```

Is the value shown a contact Id? Also when I checked the MongoDB Collection contacts, the id seems to be encrypted but I queried using email id and that had an entry.

```
_id: "E7AZylslx06grkWG/jSW7A=="
 System: {"VisitCount":0,"Value":0}
 Identifiers:
 Identifier: "testing@gmail.com"
```

Not sure why this error is occurring.

Comment: Perhaps the default list was changed. Can you check the Global Opt Out list on the settings of EXM default manager root? /sitecore/content/Email Campaign https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/setting_up_exm/the_exm_default_settings

Comment: @KoenHeye the common global listis set correctly an dthere is no entry for this email  id in the list. I saw an error in Exm log file

Comment: How does the Emails facet look on the contact in MongoDB? It should look something like this:

    "Emails" : {
        "Preferred" : "Preferred",
        "Entries" : {
            "Preferred" : {
                "SmtpAddress" : "some@email.com"
            }
        }
    },

Comment: I dont see anything like that. I see      _id: "E7AZylslx06grkWG/jSW7A=="
 System:
 VisitCount: 0
 Value: 0
 Identifiers:
 Identifier: "testing@gmail.com"
 Lease:
 ExpirationTime: 12/08/2016 10:50:00 AM (-0500)
 Owner:
 Identifier: "cluster1.gocollette.com"
 Type: 0

Comment: Also I found a blog post, that kind of matches my scenario https://ryantucknz.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/engagement-plan-action-no-email-address-associated-with-recipient/#more-4 but I didnt quiet understand why sending email had to be associated to sitecore user and not a xDb contact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EXM requires an email to be associated with the contact. The contact has to be an xDB contact. Starting from EXM 3.1, Sitecore users are no longer supported.

By default the contact should look something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : LUUID("84ad2c30-71b9-a445-a424-a597867876b8"),
    "Identifiers" : {
        "IdentificationLevel" : 2,
        "Identifier" : "test@somedomain.net"
    },
    "Tags" : {
        "Entries" : {
            "ContactLists" : {
                "Values" : {
                    "0" : {
                        "Value" : "{D4DFC0A6-071E-46D8-B32A-2858D9FCFD7C}",
                        "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-12-08T11:32:59.787Z")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Personal" : {
        "FirstName" : "FirstName",
        "Surname" : "Surname"
    },
    "Emails" : {
        "Preferred" : "Preferred",
        "Entries" : {
            "Preferred" : {
                "SmtpAddress" : "test@somedomain.net"
            }
        }
    },
    "Lease" : null,
    "System" : {
        "VisitCount" : 2,
        "Value" : 0
    }
}
```

Notice the **Emails** facet. By default the **Preferred** email of this facet is used. This is loaded in the **AssignEmailProperties** pipeline processor of the **getXdbContactRecipient** pipeline.

The error message you're seeing in the log file is logged specifically when this processor hasn't loaded the email.

It is possible to change how the email is retrieved, but in your case the problem is most likely that there's no email address associated at all, and not that you've got it stored in a different facet.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use List Manager

1. From Sitecore Launchpad, click **List Manager**.
2. Click on "Contact Lists" from left menu.
3. Search for your Contact List, the Opt Out list.
4. Click on the list.
5. Do a search for the email address in the list.

   - There appears to be an bug in List Manager where it doesn't accurately match strings, so I generally use partial strings.